# Power Grid : Start of game

Tags: power-grid

When player 1 has placed a house on a city, can player 2 place his/her first house on a city in the same coloured area as player 1's house, or must player 2 start in a different coloured area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Players can put their starting house in any city that another player does not have a house, including one that shares a region with another player's starting house (as long as its in one of the regions that are in play for that game).

The rules state:

> Each player starts his network by choosing any city (not already chosen by another player) in the playing areas (chosen at the beginning of the game) on the map.

Players have to be able to play in the same region as another player because in a 6 player game, there are only 5 regions in play, and so at least two players will start in the same region.

Regions only matter for what areas are and aren't in play.  They have no other effect on game-play.

Comment: How would the regions be selected?

Comment: @RobertMiller the regions are selected at the start of the game by whatever mechanism you want (you chose, all players agree, or choose at random are typical methods)

Comment: As a justification for 2 players starting in the same region, you state that «... in a 6 player game, there are only 5 regions in play,» The maps I have seen all have 7 regions. Why would only 5 be used in a 6 player game?

Comment: @RobertMiller USA, Germany, China, and Korea all have 6 regions.  What maps are you looking at?

Comment: My mistake, I meant the maps I have seen have 6 regions (not 7), so why, in a 6-player game, would we use only 5 regions if 6 are available? We use USA and Germany, of course, and France, Italy, UK, Québec, Brazil, Spain & Portugal, Northern Europe, United Kingdom & Ireland...

Comment: @RobertMiller I assume the main reason is to increase the variety of the game to make a map more replayable.  By always having at least one region out of play, each map has essentially 6 variations that you can do.